# How can I import animated 2D content from Animate CC into Unity?

Tags: unity, animation, skeletal-animation

I'm a programmer making his efforts to get a bit into art. I have basic drawing and animation knowledge that I think is enough to have some simple games rolling.

I have used several programs to create content for unity like aseprite (pixel art), photoshop, spine, etc... but these last days I discovered Animate CC (aka old Flash) and it seems to be a really nice tool. The ability to animate + create vector graphics in the same program really attracts me.

When I create an animated asset in Animate CC, how can I import it into Unity? I imagine I won't be able to import the svg animation but I think it should be somehow possible to build a sprite sheet from it and import it into unity.

Could anyone suggest a comfortable workflow to do this?

Comment: We don't typically answer questions about what tools to use - [a quick Google search will lead you to several options](https://www.google.ca/search?q=flash+to+unity&oq=flash+to+unity), in addition to the brute force approach of just exporting a sprite sheet of all the composed & rasterized frames you want to use.